# how to use "name in (name1,name2)" in lucene query

Tags: lucene, dotcms

How do I use "where field in (value1,value2,value3)" in lucene query?

I'm using lucene query in dotCMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, this query would be equivalent:

```
field:value1 OR field:value2 OR field:value3
```